# Integrate the local maven plugin with remote repository

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have created a simple maven plugin and installed it in my local repo(.m2). Now I want to use that plugin with a git repo(maven project). How can I do that?

Currently, I am trying to build my git repo using Jenkins and it throws below error-

`[ERROR] Plugin sample.plugin:hello-maven-plugin:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact sample.plugin:hello-maven-plugin:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

I believe simply changing the pom file of my git repo won't work. What should I do so that it resolves the plugin dependency by looking into the .m2 dir first

Answer (score 0):

Your Jenkins probably deploys to a Nexus or Artifactory server. That server is also the right place to manage your plugin.